# Time series forecasting, analysing stationarity

Tags: python, time-series, arima

I have a yearly data of carbon emission from 1990 to 2017(28 datapoints) and I want to perform Time series forecasting on it. The rolling mean of the data with a window of 2 keeps increasing with time that indicates my data is not stationary but dicky-fuller test gives a p-value of 0.04 which is less then 0.05, hence this indicates that the data is stationary.
What can be done in this situation?

```
def rolling_stats(time_data):
     rolling_mean=time_data.rolling(2).mean()
     rolling_std=time_data.rolling(2).std()
     raw_data=plt.plot(time_data,color="blue",label="Original Data")
     mean=plt.plot(rolling_mean,color="green",label="mean")
     std=plt.plot(rolling_std,color="red",label="std")
     plt.legend(loc="best")
     plt.title("Mean and standard deviation")
     plt.xlabel("Years")
     plt.ylabel("Carbon emitted in megatonnes")
rolling_stats(CarbonEmitted)
```

[image]

Comment: It appears your question isn't about programming, but about statistics? If you have code you need to solve a problem with, please include it and you probably also want to include the data and the code to show the plot, instead of an image, since the image doesn't appear to be what you're having a problem with.

Comment: I have used adfuller for dicky-fuller test and pd.rolling().mean() to find the rolling mean

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing the code/data it's hard to see what you did wrong, for example, you could have performed adfuller on the standard deviation or something. Your data should be of the format

| Date | Emission |
| --- | --- |
| 1992-01-01 | 21 |
| 1993-01-01 | 20.5 |

Date is usually set as the index and your dates should be of the type datetime

Comment: Yes, it is of the same format. My index are the dates of type datetime and i have the emission values.

Comment: So if you type df.plot() it just gives a slowly increasing line?

Comment: Yes. For the original data, without any transformation or differencing, it is just a slowly increasing line

Comment: Perhaps try other tests like KPSS or Philip Peron , I understand you will want and possibly need ADF to work but these tests are testing for a unit root, which infers non- stationarity. Maybe investigate why adf thinks a unit root is not present. The value at time t should equal the value at t-1 + noise for the unit root to exist.

Answer (score 0):

The ADF test is used to determine if differencing the data will create staionairty, thus inferring that the current data is not. I don't have your data so I cannot tell if it does, but what you want to test is whether differencing the data results in random noise centered at 0.
If you do not get stationary data when performing ADF then that may be why ADF is failing on your original data.

There are other tests you can look into, sometimes differencing isn't required to make data stationary and a log transform is more appropriate, experiment with your data and see.